# Maven deploy plugin not working

Tags: java, maven-3, parent-pom

I have a below configuration in my pom.xml and I want to deploy using maven deploy plugin goal.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-file</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <groupId>com.my.build</groupId>
                        <artifactId>my_build</artifactId>
                        <version>${version}</version>
                        <packaging>zip</packaging>
                        <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        <repositoryId>dsnexus</repositoryId>
                        <url>https://dsnexus.xxxcontent/repositories/releases</url>
                        <file>target/my_build-${version}.zip</file>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>dsnexus</id>
        <name>Repo</name>
        <url>
            https://dsnexus.xxxcontent/repositories/releases
        </url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I tried using below command and its working-

```
     mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=target/my_build-1.5.5.zip -DrepositoryId=dsnexus -Durl=https://dsnexus.xxxcontent/repositories/releases
         -DgroupId=com.my.build -DartifactId=my_build -Dversion=1.5.5 -Dpackaging=zip
```

But when I run below its failing. I want to deploy zip without specifing full info like above-

```
     mvn deploy:deploy-file

  Error:
        Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterException: The parameters 'file', 'url' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy-file are missing or invalid
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:576)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:529)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:92)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

`mvn deploy:deploy-file` fails if some information is not specified, as suggests the official documentation at this page: [mvn deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html)